# Creating MySQL Triggers

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have some experience with mysql but have never created a trigger.  I have two tables in my database, books and series.  The series has a primary key series_id that is also a foriegn key constraint on books.  I want to create a trigger so that when a row in the series table is updated, all books related to that series are also deleted.  I understand the basic mysql syntax to do this, but I'm not sure how to make a trigger out of this.

I've tried reading through some tutorials, but I'm still not clear.  The tutorials all create test tables...do I need to do this?  Also, how do I pass a parameter, or can I?

Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just to clarify, do you want to delete the books when the series is edited in any way, or just when the series is deleted?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that you'll need to explicitly create a trigger for this.  Just have the foreign key use the cascade on delete.  The documentation for it is [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html).

Comment: However, if your goal is to learn how to use triggers then http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/databases/introduction-to-mysql-triggers/ is a great place.